ERROR Error: NG04002: Cannot match any routes. URL Segment: 'agregar-producto'
Usign angular
enter image description here
this are the files i am using
the app.component.ts
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { RouterOutlet } from '@angular/router';
import { ProductoListaComponent } from "./producto-lista/producto-lista.component";

@Component({
selector: 'app-root',
standalone: true,
templateUrl: './app.component.html',
styleUrl: './app.component.css',
imports: \[RouterOutlet, ProductoListaComponent\]
})
export class AppComponent {
title = 'inventario-app';
}

this is the App.compoment,html
<div class="container">
  <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark" style="background-color: #8c0aef;">
      <div class="container-fluid">
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="/productos">Sistema de Inventarios</a>
        <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#navbarNav" aria-controls="navbarNav" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
          <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
        </button>
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNav">
          <ul class="navbar-nav">
            <li class="nav-item">
              <a class="nav-link active" aria-current="page" href="/productos">Inicio</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
              <a class="nav-link" href="/agregar-producto">Agregar Producto</a>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
    </nav>
</div>

<div class="container">
  <router-outlet></router-outlet>
</div>

app.routes i don't know if the error is in this part because i am did both the productos and agregar producto path exactly the same
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { RouterModule, Routes } from '@angular/router';
import { AgregarProductoComponent } from './agregar-producto/agregar-producto.component';
import { ProductoListaComponent } from './producto-lista/producto-lista.component';

// http:localhost:4200/productos
export const routes: Routes = [
    { path: 'productos', component: ProductoListaComponent },
    { path: '', redirectTo: 'productos', pathMatch: 'full' },
    { path: 'agregar-producto', component: AgregarProductoComponent}
];

@NgModule({
    imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes)], 
    exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class AppRoutes {}

app.config.server
import { mergeApplicationConfig, ApplicationConfig } from '@angular/core';
import { provideServerRendering } from '@angular/platform-server';
import { appConfig } from './app.config';
import { provideHttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';

const serverConfig: ApplicationConfig = {
providers: \[
provideServerRendering(),
provideHttpClient()
\]
};

export const config = mergeApplicationConfig(appConfig, serverConfig);

app.config
import { ApplicationConfig } from '@angular/core';
import { provideRouter } from '@angular/router';
 
import { routes } from './app.routes';
import { provideClientHydration } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import {provideHttpClient} from '@angular/common/http';
 
export const appConfig: ApplicationConfig = {
  providers: [
    provideRouter(routes), 
    provideClientHydration(),
    provideHttpClient()
  ]
};

for now i am trying to get the next view but i dont know why it cant find agregar producto
enter image description here

When working with angular routing, we should not use href, we have to use the routerLink, the advantage of the latter is that, the screen does not refresh fully and work as a single page application, href will cause the screen to reload, which is very non angular!
Also notice that for routerLink to work, you must have the imports RouterLink or RouterModule added to the imports array of the app component as shown below!
app.component.html
<a class="navbar-brand" routerLink="/productos">Sistema de Inventarios</a>
<a class="nav-link active" aria-current="page" routerLink="/productos">Inicio</a>
<a class="navbar-brand" routerLink="/productos">Sistema de Inventarios</a>

app.component.ts
import { RouterModule } from '@angular/router';
...

...
@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  standalone: true,
  imports: [RouterModule]
  ...
})
...

